Openssl ecb decryption comamnd got 'bad decrypt'
I am trying to use the OpenSSL 1.0.2p to do the encryption/decryption with ECB.
The command like:
openssl enc -aes-256-ecb -e -in abc -out abc_en -k 1122334455
This works fine, but when I try to decrypt like:
openssl enc -aes-256-ecb -d -in abc_en -out abc_1 -k 1122334455
and got:
bad decrypt
3080656072:error:06065064:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt:evp_enc.c:531:
I don't know why the decryption does not work. Can anyone help me with this? Thanks in advance.

I use the -K to replace -k, then it works now.
like:
openssl enc -aes-256-ecb -e -in abc -out abc_en -K 1122334455
openssl enc -aes-256-ecb -d -in abc_en -out abc_1 -K 1122334455
